# Text disappearing in IE 11 on Windows 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, bourbon

I'm using Bourbon, which produces the following code.

The problem is that no text is shown in Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7. It works fine with all the other browsers I've tried (Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1 for example).

The problem is in `font-feature-settings: "kern","liga","pnum";` line, generated automatically by Bourbon/Neat I guess.

Should I remove it, or is there a better solution? I really have no clue on what is going on, I was only able to spot the problematic line.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
            font-feature-settings: "kern","liga","pnum";
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    Test
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `IE10` and `11` on `Windows 7` can hide the text under certain circumstances.

visit http://caniuse.com/#feat=font-feature, it has brief explanation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSIE 10, web font and font-feature-settings causes invisible text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151835/msie-10-web-font-and-font-feature-settings-causes-invisible-text)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

https://jsfiddle.net/aakashshah/sLc2nmnq/2/

Rather than giving font for the whole body, define a class with `<div>` element and and add it just below the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer: [MSIE 10, web font and font-feature-settings causes invisible text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151835/msie-10-web-font-and-font-feature-settings-causes-invisible-text/33344512#33344512)

A bug in Windows 7 is causing text to disappear in IE10 and IE11 when the font-feature-settings css property is used. https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/831964